# Keyboard will not work for encrypted login

Tags: grub2, login, 15.04, encryption, ubuntu-gnome

I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 (Ubuntu gnome). When I start the computer, it shows the gnome logo and asks to enter my encrypted password to unlock the disk. However, I cannot enter the password.

Nothing happens if I type the password or hit Enter. Not really sure what to do. The only way I can log in is if I use a PS/2 keyboard, but I don’t want this to be permanent, I would like to go back to my wireless USB keyboard.

Comment: If you change the tty (e.g. Ctrl+Alt+F5) can you enter your login name using the keyboard?